# Not observing Ramadan for medical / weight reasons

Tags: sawm, ramadan, sick

What's the status for this case ?

A person was ill. Because of his illness he lost lot of weight. He've been hospitalized and then he started a new treatement !

The treatement helped him gaining weight, but it was difficult for him, a fight for every pound.

Before the beginning of Ramadhan, the doctor told him that he was under the weight standards of a healthy person (he's under by about 22 pounds) and that he had to gain more weight, to maintain his health and also because his medication's dosage depends on that : if he loose weight, he have to decrease his medication.

For that the doctor advised him not to do the *sawm* during the Ramadhan.

So he decided to follow the doctor advocation (of course, he gives the *Sadaqa* for each day), but he feels bad about it even if he knows that loosing weight is not preconized for him, not only because it would be a step back physically but also psychologically (regarding the difficulty he had to gain those pounds)

So, what's your opinion on this case ?

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

For the issue of who can leave the fast, **medical condition is subjected to be life threatening** (as mejority of ulama say).

Now, if he lose weight and doctors say **it can be threat to his life, than he must not fast. Its as much obligatory for him to not fast as it was obligatory for him to fast when he was healthy**.

Now, we don't know if doctor was a MUTTAQI(having fear of allah, and muslim) or he was a non-muslim, if a muttaqi doctor advices a person to not fast, he should not. But if a non-muslim doctor or a doctor who has no knowledge about islam is recommending not to fast, than we have to look up a few things.

> Al-Nawawi said in al-Majmoo’, 6/261:
>
> The person who is unable to fast because of a sickness which he hopes
>   will go away is not obliged to fast… This applies if he encounters
>   obvious difficulty in fasting and is not subject to the condition that
>   he reaches a point when he is unable to fast. Rather our companions
>   said: The permission not to fast is subject to the condition that
>   fasting causes him difficulties that it is hard for him to bear.”

Now in this specific case, its **22 pounds which is about 9/10kg**. Which does not seem very much which might cause him any severe issues. So my advice is to have a discussion about this with a muttaqi doctor with all your reports etc. And if he also suggest you to not fast. Than you should not.

Also read [What is the sickness which permits a fasting person to break his fast?](https://islamqa.info/en/12488) fatwa for more clear understanding of who can leave fast because of illness.

It also **depends on person's taqwa and will for ajar**, because fasting of ramazan is very important, as i have heard a saying of prophet s.a.w.w that

> **(If a person does not fast for a single day in Ramadan, he cannot earn
>   the reward of this single day, even if he fasts all the year round
>   instead of it.) [Tirmidhi]**

So, ramazan is very important don't take it lightly, but if a muttaqi doctor says you must not fast than you are practically not allowed to fast.

Hope it answers the question.

### Allah knows best

Comment: As far as I know, it's a muslim doctor, and the person concerned takes **Ramadhan** seriously. I don't agree however when you say 10 kg is not very much. We're not talking about someone weighting 70kg but about someone who is by now already under the limit from which we can medicaly begin to talk of anemia and malnutrition risks. Fasting would take him even lower.
So yes It's probably not life threatening, but I don't think it's allowed in Islam to do something that may increase risks for your health. 
Thanks anyway for your answer !

Comment: @Koblenz thats exactly i said that a muttaqi doctor should suggest, because i am not a doctor to determine this kind of things.